# Some Routing problems in laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am new to laravel 4 framework but was previously working on CI and CakePHP, i have some problems with routes in it (i may sound nerd, so bear with me.)

-> If i have 3 controller userController,adminController,editorController and many methods inside them, do i need to define routes for every methods inside it (ofcourse i am not using ResourceFull controller for them). Can't i have something by which the methods can be accessed by using the controllername followed by method name like we do in other frameWork.
E.g usersController have manageUser method, i wnt to access it like

```
http://localhost/project/users/manageUser
```

-> What is use of defining a route using **Route::controller('users', 'UserController');** or restfull controller?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write 
Route::controller('users', 'UserController') 
runs the default function (index of all the objects), but you can write:

Route::get('/users', 'userController@function');
or
Route::post('/users', 'userController@function');

this route shows to Laravel what controller and function can call when you write this route, the diference is if you pass the parameters with get or post mode.

Hope I help you